# Salesforce Instance refresh - new instance name "UM"

Tags: administration, admin, instance

What does the UM stand for in the in the Salesforce instance naming?
EU: Europe
NA: North America
UM:????

Is it new or has it always been present? Never noticed it and I have just found out that my instance will be there in January

Comment: Where did you get "UM" at all? I checked their [Trust](https://status.salesforce.com/products/all) site and haven't found any instance with that abbreviation.

Comment: EXACTLY! but on the instance locations there is! https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=000257307&language=en_US&type=1

Comment: Sometimes Salesforce has custom instances for demo / pre-release /webinars like GS which is not mentioned in trust, The one you mentioned UM  seems like the same.

Comment: What mail you got with respect to UM ? is it related to org migration to new Instance? Which region are you based?

Comment: @PranayJaiswal what is 'GS' -- also does that mean it will change to an 'EU' instance after the pre-release? Is there any documentation to support this?
Email: ATTENTION: Your new instance name will be UM4 following the  instance refresh on January 19
https://status.salesforce.com/maintenances/28535

Comment: This article mentions about pre-release org GSO which I have. https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=000214172&type=1

Answer (score 4):

It refer to London, UK (North) / London, UK (West).

> As per docs: We will soon have two geographically dispersed data
>   centers in the London, UK metropolitan area - London, UK (North) and
>   London, UK (West).

[Where is my Salesforce instance located?](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=000257307&language=en_US&type=1)

Comment: I know, but my question was different... what does it stand for? + has it always been there? (on trust it isnt there!)

Comment: @TheAdmin Not sure but maybe UK metropolitan(UM). This is not on trust site because they are still new and Salesforce didn't move any customer site on them so no need. Not quite sure.

Comment: All UK customers I met has EU instance, I dont know if it was a specific requirement after BREXIT to move data from Europe data centers to UK data Centers.

Comment: ^^^ That is exactly my concern! but there are no articles that describe this! (especially as we aren't even based in the UK!)

Comment: According to GDPR stuff I heard, EU data should be inside EU no matter what, after brexit that wont be the case so I dont know if UM should even be considered for your org migration. The best bet is to raise a case or mail your account manager

Comment: @TheAdmin yes they are the better person to answer this.

Answer (score 2):

From a SF slide deck "Tech Updates December 2018 Edition":

*"Going forward, we will have two separate subregions within the EMEA region: **UMEA 
(UK, Middle East & Africa)** and **EU (Rest of Europe & Russia)** with UM and EU instances, 
respectively. UM instances will be supported by two data centers in the London, UK metro area and EU instances will be supported by our France & Germany data centers. "*

Full overview of instances and location, as already mentioned in another answer, see https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=000257307&language=en_US&type=1